# Getting the right value of a CheckBox in a DataGridView CheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `CheckBox` column in a `DataGridView` called `Status` and When I `check` or `uncheck` it, I want to update `true` of `false` in the database. Currently I have following method which is supposed to do this.

When a particular row is selected, the `SelectedEmployeeID` property and `StatusOfSelectedEmployee` property are assigned the values accurately. But what am I trying to achieve is I want to do that when I `check` or `uncheck` the `CheckBox` not when select the row. Now when I click on a `CheckBox` only the `SelectedEmployeeID` property is assigned the right value. `StatusOfSelectedEmployee` is always `false`.

```
private void DGV_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    SelectedEmployeeID = DGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["EmployeeID"].Value.ToString();
    StatusOfSelectedEmployee = Convert.ToBoolean(DGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["EmployeeStatus"].Value);

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 10 & e.RowIndex != -1) //CheckBox column's col_index is 10
    {
        OnChangeEmployeeStatus(sender, e); //This will update the status
    }

}
```

1. How to get the right value to `StatusOfSelectedEmployee` property?
2. How to avoid hard coding in the if condition using column names instead of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try using the `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` event. it is fired after you change your values

2) Get the column index using `Datagridview1.Columns["columnName"].Index`